# How to represent a binary vector in Python efficiently

Tags: python, optimization, vector, binary

I'm doing data analysis (e.g. using Local Binary Pattern) on Python and I'm trying to optimize my code. In my code I'm using binary vectors which are implemented currently as `numpu ndarray` vectors. Here are three functions from my code:

```
# Will return a binary vector presentation of the neighbourhood
#
# INPUTS:
# 'ndata' numpy ndarray consisting of the neighbourhood X- and Y- coordinates and values 
# 'thres' decimal value indicating the value of the center pixel
#
# OUTPUT:
# 'bvec' binary vector presentation of the neighbourhood 

def toBinvec(ndata, thres):

    bvec = np.zeros((len(ndata), 1)) 
    for i in range(0, len(ndata)):
        if ndata[i, 2]-thres < 0:
            bvec[i] = 0
        else:
            bvec[i] = 1
    return bvec 



# Will check whether a given binary vector is uniform or not 
# A binary pattern is uniform if when rotated one step, the number of
# bit values changing is <= 2
#
# INPUTS:
# 'binvec' is a binary vector of type numpy ndarray 
#
# OUTPUT:
# 'True/False' boolean indicating uniformness

def isUniform(binvec):

    temp = rotateDown(binvec) # This will rotate the binary vector one step down
    devi = 0
    for i in range(0, len(temp)):
        if temp[i] != binvec[i]:
            devi += 1
    if devi > 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True

# Will return the corresponding decimal number of binary vector
#
# INPUTS:
# 'binvec' is a binary vector of type numpy ndarray 
#
# OUTPUT:
# 'value' The evaluated decimal value of the binary vector 

def evaluate(binvec):

    value = 0
    for i in range(0, len(binvec)):
            value += binvec[i]*(2**i)
    return value
```

Is there some other way I should implement my binary vectors in order to make the code more efficient? The code is to be used with Big Data analysis, so efficiency is an important matter.

I also need to do some manipulation to the binary vectors, e.g. rotating it, evaluating its decimal value etc.

Thank you for any help / hints! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def toBinvec(ndata, thres):
    return  np.where(ndata[:,2] < thres, 0, 1 ).reshape(-1,1)

def isUniform(binvec):

    temp = rotateDown(binvec) # This will rotate the binary vector one step down
    if (np.count_nonzero(binvec!=temp)) > 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def evaluate(binvec):
    return sum(binvec * 2**np.arange(len(binvec)))
```

this should give some improvement. But most of this seems like something that will be available as dedicated in some of the scipy ( or related) packages in highly optimized version.

for example `toBinvec` is just a threshold, and that is available in many packages.